# Access "Not In" query not working while only In is working correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have below given query which is working fine but I want to use "Not In" operator instead of "In" but its giving no results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderProdDetails.Priority
FROM OrderProdDetails
WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.Priority) In (SELECT DISTINCT OrderProdDetails.Priority 
FROM OrderProdDetails WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.OrdID)=[Forms]![UpdateOrder]![OdrID])))));
```

Desired Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderProdDetails.Priority
FROM OrderProdDetails
WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.Priority) Not In (SELECT DISTINCT OrderProdDetails.Priority 
FROM OrderProdDetails WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.OrdID)=[Forms]![UpdateOrder]![OdrID])))));
```

Basically it is referencing a control on parent form and based on that in a subform I want to populate the priority numbers i.e 1,2,3 and if for that record 1 is entered I want to get only 2 and 3 as drop-down option.

```
  ReocordID OrdID   Brand Name  Priority
   2          1       Org 1        2
   3          2       Org 2        1
   4          1       Org 1        1
   6          1       Org 1        3
   7          3       Org 3        1
   8          4       Org 1        1
   9          5       Org 2        1
   10         5       Org 2        2
   11         6       Org 1        1
  12          6       Org 2        2
```

If there is any other better approach for the same please suggest.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So many parenthesis :S but your query looks good to me. If you show us what data looks like in that table, I can help you further.

Comment: @SK . . . I removed the extraneous database tags.  When asking a question, try to limit the tags only to the relevant tags for the question.

Comment: A side note: Don't use `[NOT] IN (SELECT DISTINCT xyz ...`. Tell the DBMS what to do, not how to do it. Hence: `[NOT] IN (SELECT xyz ...`. (The DBMS may or may not make the records distinct internally, whichever deems it more suitable.)

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, your problem is that `Priority` can take on `NULL` values.  In that case, `NOT IN` doesn't work as expected (although it does *work* technically).  The usual advice is to always use `NOT EXISTS` with subqueries rather than `NOT IN`.

But, in your case, I would suggest conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT opd.Priority
FROM OrderProdDetails as opd
GROUP BY opd.Priority
HAVING SUM(IIF(opd.OrdID = [Forms]![UpdateOrder]![OdrID], 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of times the forms `OdrId` is in the orders.  The `= 0` means it is never there.  Plus, you no longer need a `select distinct`.

Comment: It's saying wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'SUM(IIF(opd.OrdID) = [Forms]![UpdateOrder]![OdrID], 1, 0) = '.
.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your prompt answers however I figured out what the problem was and the answer to problem is.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderProdDetails.Priority
FROM OrderProdDetails
WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.Priority) Not In (SELECT OrderProdDetails.Priority
FROM OrderProdDetails WHERE (((OrderProdDetails.OrdID)=[Forms]![UpdateOrder]![OdrID]) 
and ((OrderProdDetails.Priority) Is not null) ))));
```

I realized that the problem was happening only to those where there was a null value in priority so I puth the check of not null and it worked fine.

Thanks

Comment: I guess it wasn't to hard to "figure out what the problem was" after Gordon *told* you in his answer ;-) Yes, `Priority` can be null, so the `NOT IN` fails in case the subquery returns a null. Gordon has also shown you a better way to approach the problem. (Admittedly, he had a syntax error on IIF, which he corrected, but with the error message given, you should have been able to understand and correct the error yourself.)